# Dropdown "OnSelectedIndexChanged" Event Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown as

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="Month Name" DataValueField="Year"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

For my dropdown binding I'm retrieving data form dataset and filtering data based on some condition as shown below. Then converting to datatable and binding to dropdown

**Binding** :

```
        DataRow[] rows = ds.Tables[0].Select("Year = '2015'");
        DataTable dt = rows.CopyToDataTable();
        ddl.DataSource = dt;
        ddl.DataBind();
```

Binding is happening nicely but my `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event not firing.
I found out that is due to the binding, whats wrong am I doing

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: When is data binding happening? I mean, is it on Page_Load? Are you checking post backs?

Comment: On page load When it is not postback @Andrei 1

Comment: Have you included `ddl_SelectedIndexChanged` in code behind ?

Comment: Yes, the breakpoint is not firing in the event

Comment: Another idea just came into my mind. Is this dropdown a standalone one, or does it reside inside some databound control template, say gridview?

Comment: Can you add `ddl_SelectedIndexChanged` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should also add properties `ViewStateMode="Enabled"` and `EnableViewState="true"`

Comment: Sorry, even this doesn't helped me out

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Autopostback property
 AutoPostBack="true"